# What is this kind of database modelling called and how is it beneficial?

Tags: database, database-design, data-modeling, nosql

I have moved to a new workplace where we have this particular architecture for database. The database architecture is driven by 4 tables

**1) Master Type**

Here you define column code, name and description

row 1 - EmpID - Id for the employee

row 2 - EmpName - Name of the employee

**2) Master Type Data**

Here you define column code-value as rows

row 1 - EmpId - 123

row 2 - EmpId - 124

row 3 - EmpName - John

row 4 - EmpName - Jason

**3) Master Type Mapping**

Here you map which columns can be mapped

row 1 - EmpId - EmpName

**4) Master Type Mapped Data**

Here you map the values of columns

row 1 - Id of Master Type Data row 1 - Id of Master Type Data row 3

row 2 - Id of Master Type Data row 2 - Id of Master Type Data row 4

This way you can create any number of table/columns/relationship inside the structure. Does anyone know what such kind of Database Architecture called? and what are the benefits? I am finding it hard to find it's benefits, after seeing how much complexity it adds in to adding, maintaining and understanding the data.

I have been told that it saves you from creating hundreds of tables and memory of those columns in tables which would be null. I have worked extensively on RDBMS  and don't have experience working in NoSQL DB, but i think that's how NoSQL anyways work behind the screen?

Comment: We might call it Greenspun's 10th data model - an ad hoc, informally-specified, bug-ridden, slow implementation of half of a database inside a database. Or more simply, a dumb idea. The overhead in this design is likely to outweigh the storage requirements of nulls, and rather than save you from creating lots of structures, it prevents you from easily seeing or maintaining any structure in the data, maintaining integrity, indexes, etc. It's quite possible to design normalized tables without nulls.

Comment: I'd call it "bad practice".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"I am finding it hard to find it's benefits, after seeing how much complexity it adds in to adding, maintaining and understanding the data."

That is the only thing you need to remember about this horrible idea.  (Which, by the way, is usually labeled under the generic name of "EAV" or "Entity Attribute Value".  (google that term and you will find lots of praise as well as lots of puking over it.  You assess and judge the respective arguments.)

"Generic name" because in fact many many variants are possible that all differ in some small detail.  By way of illustration : yours is a variant that replaces the commonly-present notion of an "entity ID" with a "mapping" between recorded entity attribute values. Your conception of that mapping is for it to be binary (not unusual for something called a "mapping"), which poses additional problems if you want to "map" more than two entity attribute values together.)

That said, if you are in the rare circumstance where all of the following are true :

*- you truly genuinely are facing "sparse" data*
*- the nature of the data changes all the time (once a year is not "all the time")*
*- there is no dba skill available for addressing this problem the right way (= the dba way), or the impact on the applications of addressing it the right way is too massive and daunting*
*- and the inevitable lack of any form of integrity enforcement on the data is not a problem for the business*

then you'll likely be using a scheme like this to tackle your problem.